# angular.json exclude assets for dev build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a `robots'txt` file I want to include for only my dev builds.

How can I set angular.json up so that `ng build --prod` does not include robots.txt and `ng build` does?

Ideally, I would like to extend from configuration prod and add robots.txt in addition like so:

```json
// ...
{
  "dev": {
    "assets": [
      "extend_here",
      "src/robots.txt"
    ]
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using Angular `environments`. By default Angular application can be built to `development` environment or to `production` environment.

> When application is built for production mode then `environments/environment.ts` file gets replaced with `environments/environment.prod.ts` file. Hence if you are referring to settings from `environment.ts` file in your code, you don’t have to put.

You can create a config for your `robots.txt` with different values like this:

**environment.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  robotLink: 'src/robots.txt',
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  robotLink: '',
};
```

and in any `Component` or `Service` that want to use it, check the file from `environment` and if it exist use it:

**Service.ts**

```js
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {  
  
  robotUrl = environment.robotLink;

  constructor() { }

  getData() {
    if (robotUrl) {
    // put your code here
    }
  }
}
```

For more information about `environments` visit this [link](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/configure-and-build-angular-application-for-different-environments-7e94a3c0af23).

In addition, Inside your `angular.json` file there is a configurations object projects.{project-name}.architect.build.configurations. Set the assets inside the prod entry to [].

Comment: Ah yes, the environment approach might work (though not exactly what I want...) Setting the prod entry to `[]` is a no no as this stops from adding any assets. angular.json is 
quite a disappointment when it comes to flexibility...